# Error while updating webdriver-manager

Tags: node.js, windows, selenium, protractor, webdriver-manager

I'm following the Protractor [tutorial](http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial), but I'm getting the following error while updating webdriver-manager:

```
C:/Users/emelo/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/built/lib/webdriver.js:3
const minimist = require("minimist");

SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode. at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)     
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25) 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10) 
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32) 
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12) 
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17) 
    at require (module.js:384:17) 
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\emelo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protr actor\bin\webdriver-manager:3:1) 
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26) 
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

I'm using npm v2.11.3 and node v0.12.7.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would try updating your node (and maybe npm too), node `v6.10` is LTS right now, you are quite behind on versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to be on at least NodeJS version 6 or higher, see [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/package.json#L82), if you are using Protractor 5 or higher.

So you'll need to upgrade your environment first.

Comment: Thanks @wswebcreation! Updating node to its newest version solved my problem.